# Why can't I read indefinately doubles using this loop?

Tags: java, double, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read some data from a user and do some very simple calculations with them, but for some reason I can't explain, the program stops after first 2-3 inputs (given they are doubles). Can someone explain this behaviour?

My code:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your values, 'q' to quit: ");
double average, input, smallest, largest, range;
average = smallest = largest = range = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());

int counter = 1;

while (in.hasNextDouble()) {
    input = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
    smallest = input < smallest ? input: 0;
    largest = input > largest ? input: 0;
    average += input;
    counter++;
}
```

Comment: What does "program stops" mean? It just exits or there is an exception?

Comment: In case you are facing any exceptions, just provide the stack trace to understand what is the exact problem for "program stops" here.

Comment: It seems to be running.. What values did you try?

Comment: You can simplify: 
`Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine())`
to
`Scanner.nextDouble()`

Comment: Voted to close as unclear. This code highly depends on your input, so tell us what you enter into the console. And also explains what you mean with *"the program stops"* ... does it mean, that you get an exception, or does it just stop without a notice?

Comment: what do you use as input?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion here. As the title says, I want the program to consume doubles, possibly indefinately, but it only consumes one or two before terminating (not a compile error). Trying 2.3 on the first line, 3.4 on next, the program terminates and smallest = largest = average = 2.3, and range 0.0. It's like it have completely skipped the loop, but the condition surely should be true.

Comment: The average is divided by counter and range is just the difference between smallest and largest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this input:

```
1.23
4.56 7.89
```

To `Scanner` this looks like a valid sequence of three `double`s on two separate lines. When you call `nextLine` to obtain the first `double`, it works fine, because the number occupies the entire string.

When you do the same for the next `double`, the string that you try to parse looks like this:

```
"4.56 7.89"
```

This string is *not* a valid `double`, so you cannot parse it.

One approach to deal with this problem is to call `nextDouble`, and avoid parsing altogether. Pairing up `hasNextDouble()` with `nextDouble()` has an advantage of not requiring users to put their data on different lines.

**Note:** The first call to `Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine())` happens without checking that `Scanner` has next `double`, so your program could crash on initial bad input.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't think this is the problem, but see my comment above to prove me wrong!

Comment: @Thomas Wait ... you "think" that? So you didn't try it?

Comment: @Tom Look, I'm not receiving in strings of the form "3.3 4.5 3.4". I'm receiving strings with distinct doubles on each line, I've already written this in a comment above.

Comment: @Thomas And that doesn't matter to me, because I already tested your and dasblinkenlights version and his works like expected (your version has the reported issue, so his version fixes that). So how about spending the 2 minutes to test it yourself?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight If you like to extend your answer: OPs main problem is his origin. He is most likely from Germany or France, where they use a `,` as a delimiter instead of `.`. So he enters `3.4`, because `Double.parseDouble(..)` is locale independent, whereas `in.hasNextDouble()` is, so it expects `3,4`. That is why his `while` is immediately *false*. One can fix that with your solution or by using `new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)`.

Comment: @ Tom Yes that fixed it, thanks alot for pointing that out! Sorry for the confusion. I'll try to make my questions better in the future.

Comment: @Thomas The question was clear after your comment (that should have been added to the question ;P), but you should have more trust in answers. It can be the case that they *look* like they aren't the solution, but you should at least try them. if it indeed works, then you can ask *"why?"* :). Well and yes, if they don't work, you can say that in a comment :).